# Scala Builder a object recursively

Tags: scala, recursion

Here is the situation

```
val input = "a:b:c:d:e"

def getTrait(primary: SomeTrait, secondary: SomeTrait): SomeTrait {
...
}

def convertTrait(name: String): SomeTrait {
...
}
```

So what I want to do is to slide input in window of 2 and build SomeTrait based on that like this

```
val result = getTrait(convertTrait(a),convertTrait(b))
```

and then use this result to build another result like this

```
val resul2 = getTrait(result, convertTrait(c))
```

and so onn.......

Offcourse I wanna do it in some kind of recursion/for in scala but unable to find solution

Here is where I am

```
val listOfList = input.split(":").grouped(2).toList



private def builder(inputList: List[List[String]], primary: SomeTrait, secondary: SomeTrait): SomeTrait = {
    for {
      xs <- inputList
      fallback = if(xs.size == 1) providerFallBackChainBuilder(convertTrait(xs(0)), "noop") else providerFallBackChainBuilder(convertTrait(xs(1)), convertTrait(xs(0)))
    } yield fallback
    FallbackConfigProvider(primary, secondary)
  }
```

I  somehow need to pass this fallback back to function .. I know this is not working and not best solution but can anyone guide me on how to dit better and correctly

Comment: `"a:b:c:d:e".split(":").iterator.map(convertTrait).reduce { case (acc, elem) => getTrait(acc, elem) }`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I am getting the following error

`Error:(65, 102) missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: (?, ?) => ?
      "a:b:c:d:e".split(":").reverseIterator.map(convertTrait).reduce { case (primary, secondary) =>       FallbackConfigProvider(primary, secondary) }`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez made it to work by changing

"a:b:c:d:e".split(":").iterator.map(convertTrait).reduce ( (acc, elem) => getTrait(acc, elem) )

I do not why but putting curly brace and case dont work inside reduce

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Can I ask you to put this answer in an answer rather than a series of comments? It would be much easier for other members to get the information they need if the answer is in one place, and any comments on that answer are with that answer rather than attached to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should what you need.

```
"a:b:c:d:e".split(":").iterator.map(convertTrait).reduce(getTrait)
```

Answer (score 1):

made it to work like this  `"a:b:c:d:e".split(":").iterator.map(convertTrait).reduce ( (acc, elem) => getTrait(acc, elem) )`